# Intellij Idea is not recognizing the dart project correctly since using melos

Tags: dart, intellij-idea, multi-module, dart-packages, melos

I upgraded my project to be based on a multi-package architecture a few weeks ago.
My primary `pubspec.yaml` contains `path` references to those feature or library packages.

To be able to manage this `mono-repo` I recently introduced [melos](https://melos.invertase.dev/).

Now I have the problem that I cannot use Intellij any more as it doesn't recognize the project correctly:

- I don't see any project errors any more
- I don't see any code suggestions any more
- I cannot use shortcuts any more to e.g. jump into the implementation or the definition of a class
- and so on (The project structure seems to be broken)

What I tried to address this issue so far:

- I already ran `Repair IDE` in Intellij with all checkboxes marked including `Invalidate Caches & Restart` in the end
- I did this again but ran `melos clean` before and `melos bs` (bootstrap) after restart.
- I checked my `melos.yaml` to see that all the packages are correctly referenced.

So what else could be the problem for such a behaviour?

Running the project in VS Code works so it is related to Intellij.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue:

Short answer --> **manually delete all your `iml` files and run `melos bs` again**

Explanation: `melos` automatically creates `iml` files which are named like `melos_module.iml`. Two of my packages still had an old `iml` file called `module.iml`.  `melos clean` on the other hand didn't remove all `iml` files nor did `Repair IDE` do such a thing. So the problem with the two redundant files was never solved.

After manually removing all `iml` files in the project and running `melos bs` again I have a running project again.